# i have a this string 1=>aaabba;2=>bsbsbsb

Tags: php

i have a this string `1=>aaabba;4=>bsbsbsb;7=>flkdsl;5=>jdsfkjhsfd;` 
I want to change it in an array with such form:

```
[1] => aaabba
[4] => sbsbsb
[7] => flkdsl
[5] => jdsfkjhsfd
```

how to do it?

Language PHP.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Hint : Use explode function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$result_array = array();
$str = "1=>aaabba;4=>bsbsbsb;7=>flkdsl;5=>jdsfkjhsfd;";
$temp_array = explode(";",$str);
$temp_array = array_filter($temp_array);
foreach($temp_array as $val)
{
    $sub_temp_array = explode("=>",$val);   
    $result_array[$sub_temp_array[0]] = $sub_temp_array[1];
}
print_r($result_array);
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/ueMEO)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I had already thought of this solution, but I thought there was an alternative

Comment: its working fine thanks :)